# Python - webscraping - Multi threading - Limit on threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, web-scraping

I have a code to retrieve search results from website.

The ExtractDetails function is a big search function that searches the websites.

```
LangList = ['91','32','69','A9','48','62','01','75','34','73','B1',
'68','61','20','03','35','36','86','87','AS','63','04','AO','65','57','05','AE','06','AC','07','08','A4','37','72','70',
'38','09','95','10','A1','B0','AL','A8','39','AT','94','11','84','12','59','AG','AB','13','40','14','AW','67','98','AJ',
'41','15','74','16','33','17','AU','AV','A0','42','92','AI','18','AD','A2','43','AM','44','45','A3','85','58','83','71',
'21','22','A6','90','AR','99','46','78','23','24','76','AP','25','26','AN','47','60','97','49','56','27','93','AZ','02',
'28','77','AA','29','50','A5','64','51','52','AQ','AY','A7','80','30','53','54','31','96','79','89','55','66','82','81']
Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
SearchCriteria=[Alphabet] * len(LangList)
for Lang , alphabets in LostConn.items():
    for item in alphabets:
        t = Thread(target=ExtractDetails,args=(Lang,item + '%',))
        t.start()
        th.append(t)
for thr in th:
    thr.join()
```

The problem with the script is that my laptop will hang if I run this code, because it will generate 3406 threads. My questions is how to determine the optimal number of threads on particular a laptop?

Comment: You might be interested in [ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) or [multiprocessing.pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) rather than writing the thread limiting code yourself.

Answer (score -1):

The number of threads you can run concurrently depends on your machine and the number of cores the cpu has. Most machines can run 2 threads per core. An easy way to figure out what works for your machine is in the `multiprocessing` module in Python:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

This function will show the maximum number of threads you can run concurrently. Hope this helps!

Comment: are you sure? I used to run around 113 threads at a same time.

Comment: I believe most modules will run as many as possible concurrently and keep the others you initialize in a queue. You can initialize that many threads, you just can't do anything with them unless you have a distributed cluster of computers which can take up other threads.

Comment: You can run different processes in different cores using multiprocessing. But you can run multiple threads in the same core using threading. Different things man.